# How to change text element content using Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to change the content of a text element in my SVG.
The purpose of this will be to dynamically update a mode of an object that will show up as a text element.

I have the text element wrapped in a  element as follows:

```
<g id="CarAMode">
   <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 177.17 133.6)" class="st2">PASSENGER</text>
</g>
```

I then load the SVG in JS upon loading:

```
var hoistShaft = Snap('#HoistShaft');

Snap.load( "/svg/Hoistway.svg", function(f) {
   hoistShaft.append(f);
   var carMode = hoistShaft.select('#CarAMode');

   carMode.attr({       // I thought this is how its done..
      text: 'default'
   });
}
```

After loading up my page, I expected 'PASSENGER' to become 'default' but no change occurs. I also dont get any errors in console, so syntax seems to be right.

Any help please on how I can change the text element?

Comment: You set the `text` attribute of the `CarAMode` group. Shouldn't you set it for the text element instead?

Comment: @ConnorsFan  I thought that changing any element in the SVG required it to be in a group though. If not, would I do something like `var carMode = hoistShaft.select('#idOfTextElement');`

Comment: @ConnorsFan I just tried assigning an ID for the text element and it worked! I had no idea that any element's ID could be directly selected with Snap. This whole time I thought it always had to be a group ID. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Since a group can contain several text elements, I assumed that you had to indicate which one is to be modified.

Comment: Snap just uses css selectors (behind the scenes using querySelectorAll, so you can use select and selectAll just as one would with any css selector, by id, by class or whatever.

Comment: .select('#some-id') is used to select by ID and .selectAll('.some-class') is used to iterate thru groups, typically, with a class or just a selector like 'svg text' for all text, or something like that.  I think it's good practice if you have a system of multiple SVGs and nested and that sort of thing, you should just get in the habit of having IDs on every group object that you want to be single targetable otherwise just resort to the the broader css query selectors and don't expect to target them.  That way when it comes time to target parent group elements, the IDs are always there for you.

Answer (score 0):

Given the svg code, as stated on the comments, you can select using the common CSS selection query:
`hoistShaft.select('#CarAMode text');`
or
`hoistShaft.select('#CarAMode').select('text');`